# Shell script to import mysql dump file

Tags: java, linux, mysql, shell

I'm new to mysql. My requirement is to create a shell script to import a sql dump file into mysql in linux and this script should be called by java program for the restoration to take on a button click.

Please advice me on this.

Regards,

Chandu.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done by using mysql

> mysql --user=USERNAME
>   --password=PASSWORD DATABASE < DATABASE.sql

EDIT:

To place this in a script:

file loaddb.sh:

> mysql --user=USERNAME
>   --password=PASSWORD DATABASE < $1.sql

add execute-permission by

> chmod +x loaddb.sh

you would call it:

> loaddb.sh YOURDBNAME

Comment: Hi stacker,

Thanks for ur reply. But my requirement is to create a shell script that do this job as specified in the description.

Please advice me

Comment: Chandu, add `#!/bin/bash` as the first script line, replace `DATABASE.sql` with `$1` and you're all set.

Comment: Hi Tomislav,

Thank for your reply. I'm not clear about $1 can you explain me on this? If I specified $1 then where I have to keep dump file path for restoring.

Comment: $1 is a placeholder for a parameter passed to you script

Comment: Thanks Stacker, so where should I place the execute permission "chmod +x loaddb.sh" because I want to run this script from a java program & explain me the way about how to call this script from java.

Comment: chmod is only done once, to start this from java you don't need that script see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071682/how-to-execute-sql-script-file-in-java and accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

See this; it might be beneficial:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "ENTER DATA BASE NAME:"
read dbname
echo "ENTER DATABASE USER NAME:"
read dbuser
echo "ENTER DATASE PASSWORD:"
read dbpassword
mysqldump -u $dbuser -p$dbpassword $dbname>$dbname".sql"
```