# HSQLDB Trigger Statement ERROR when using SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript()

Tags: spring, triggers, hsqldb, spring-jdbc, spring-test

I'm currently trying to load a sql script to create a HSQL database. 
This is done by using the following code:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/create-table.sql");        
SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(template, resource, Boolean.FALSE);
```

The script contains the create statement of a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE UPDATE ON SUBJECTS 
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
    SET newrow.VERSION = oldrow.VERSION + 1;
END;
```

When running the tests using this code, the following error occurs:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected end of command: REFERENCING in statement   
[CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE UPDATE ON SUBJECTS REFERENCING]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:508)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:395)
```

I'm using Spring 3.0.5 and HSQLDB (driver,...) version is 1.8.0.10.

Has anyone ever had this problem or knows how to solve this?

(I also tried to place everything on one line, placed the sql in a separate file, removed semicolons, ...)

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanx in advance!

Wendy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the trigger wasn't completely correct.
The solution became a mix of the given answers:

Update version of HSQLDB to 2.2.8 as @fredt suggested.
I changed the create script a bit:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE UPDATE ON SUBJECTS 
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow
FOR EACH ROW
    SET newrow.VERSION = oldrow.VERSION + 1;
```

Now there are no complaints about the semicolon etc.

Thanx for the help @Adi and @fredt!

Wendy

Comment: yes, "referencing new" does not work in HSQL 1.8 and "early versions of 2.0" - just stumbled on this too! beware!

Answer (score 0):

Change

> SET newrow.VERSION = oldrow.VERSION + 1;
>
> END;

to

> SET newrow.VERSION = oldrow.VERSION + 1;END;

`SimpleJdbcTestUtils` assumes ';' as delimiter if it is present in the script. So if you have single statement with multiple  ';', you need to make sure there are no new line character(\n) after ';'.

I suggest you to abandon  `SimpleJdbcTestUtils` if your statements have multiple ';' or if your script contains sql comments(try it for fun). For alternative check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071682/how-to-execute-sql-script-file-in-java) and I prefer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055008/11092) approach if you do not mind adding ant library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest version of HSQLDB (currently 2.2.8). The older versions do not support this form of CREATE TRIGGER.

When you have changed the HSQLDB jar, follow Adi's recommendation for the issue with ';'.