# Import sql script through java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am working in a java environment. I have one sql script which I have exported through Mysql Workbench. I want to import that sql script file through java code into MysqlWorkbench. How can I achieve it?

Comment: do you want to import it into a database?

Comment: no that sql script itself contains multiple database I want to import that file.

Comment: yeah but where? i guess you want to have access to the databases and therefore, they have to be embedded in an DBMS

Comment: Yes want to import in Mysql workbench

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute sql-script file in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071682/how-to-execute-sql-script-file-in-java)

Comment: You have exported is as a sql file and you want to execute it using java?

Comment: is it another mysql workbench than the one you exported it from?

Comment: Yes through java code. I have already tried the link you mentioned in comment but I want to achieve without specifying database name.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer no in same Mysql workbench

Comment: why not leave it there and not try to do anything with java?