# How to execute all sql scripts in a Folder using Java?

Tags: java, sql, database, db2, sql-scripts

I want to execute all sql-scripts in one folder via Java. It does not work because earlier it created a new schema (named like the username) and did not take the one written in the sql script. And now i get 44x the Exception showed below. Connection is working. Oh and im using a DB2.

I have tried the following approach:

```
public void sqlScripts() throws IOException, SQLException {

        File folder = new File("E:/maProject/sql");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            Statement statement = null;

            try {
                statement = con.createStatement();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                statement.execute(String.valueOf(file));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the Exception i get 44x:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-7, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=\;E:, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071682/how-to-execute-sql-script-file-in-java

Comment: No its not a duplicat

Comment: Is it necessarily to run these files with your java code? Are you allowed to run other java-based tool for that?

Comment: You are trying to execute the file _name_ instead of its contents.

Comment: @mustaccio oh yeah of course thx

Comment: @MarkBarinstein i just need to do it in java. The rest ist up to me how i do it. Any suggestions :D

Comment: `IBM Data Server Driver Package` contains JDBC-based tool called [CLPPlus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/c0053823.html). It has an ability to execute scripts. Check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mustaccio said, I tried to execute the file name instead of the contents of the file. So now what I do instead is this:

```
 public void sqlScripts() {

        try {
            File folder = new File("E:/maProject/sql");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                ScriptRunner scriptRunner = new ScriptRunner(con, false, false);

                // Give the input file to Reader
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                scriptRunner.runScript(reader);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SQLCODE=7` is `SQL0007N`

The description of the error message is

> SQL0007N  The statement was not processed because a character that is
>   not supported in SQL statements was included in the SQL statement.
>
> The specified character is not a valid character in SQL statements.
>   The "" runtime token indicates the 20 characters of the SQL
>   statement that preceded the character that is not valid.

So your invalid character is (close to) this text `\;E:`

I suspect that you are trying to run two statements in one statement. As per e.g  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2071724/9525344  you need to execute the statements one at a time